# Open balls and sets

Tags: general-topology

I've been trying to prove that an open ball is an open set, I knew that finding an open ball subset of a set would show that a set is open! Hence If i want to show that the ball $B$($x_0,r)$ is open, i shall find another ball subset to $B$ say $B'$($x_1,\delta)$, and supposing  $x_1$ belongs to $B$ and i shall find $\delta<r$ but i couldnt find $\delta$. I have tried the traingular inequality but couldnt reach anything.

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: Shall i use the triangular inequality in my proof?

Comment: Yes indeed! ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my picture :-).

[image]

Note that if $\delta+d(x_0,x_1)<r$ and $d(y,x_1) < \delta$, then
$d(y,x_0) \le d(y,x_1)+d(x_1,x_0)< \delta + d(x_1,x_0)<r$.

Hence $B(x_1,\delta) \subset B(x_0,r)$.

Comment: Well i was trying to show that d(x_1,y)<r by showing S<r anyways thankyou

Answer (score 5):

Consider $\delta = r - d(x_1, x_0)$.